# Solving Coupled Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following differential equations, for modeling predator-prey relationships:

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = Ax - Bxy$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = Cxy - Dy$$

Where A, B, C, and D are constants. How could I go about solving this? I've only really worked with basic first order differential equations before, and I've found little to help me figure this out. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: you are interested in analytical or numerical solution? Also, some qualitative analysis is possible (ie, the solution behaviour, etc)...

Comment: As far as I know, there are no analytic solution for this...

Comment: Another analytical solution is: $\left\{y(t)=0,x(t)=c_1 \exp (A t)\right\}$

Answer (score 1):

> While complete analytic solution is not likely, it's curious that we can reduce this system to a couple of nonlinear first order ODEs for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$.

Let's do this for $y$ only, since the same procedure can be applied to $x$ as well.

First, we write down some useful relationships:

$$\dot{x}=x(A-By)$$

$$Cx-D=\frac{\dot{y}}{y}$$

$$Cxy=\dot{y}+Dy$$

Now we differentiate the second equation w.r.t. $t$:

$$\ddot{y}=(Cx-D) \dot{y}+Cy \dot{x}=\frac{\dot{y}^2}{y}+(A-By)(\dot{y}+Dy)$$

Since the equation doesn't containt $t$ explicitly, we can reduce the order by the usual substitution:

$$\dot{y}=u(y), \qquad \ddot{y}=u \cdot u'$$

We obtain:

$$u u'=\frac{u^2}{y}+(A-By)(u+Dy)$$

Now we introduce another function:

$$u=y \cdot v(y), \qquad u'=v+yv'$$

We get:

$$yv(v+yv')=yv^2+(A-By)(v+D)y$$

Simplifying, we obtain:

$$y v v'=(A-By)(v+D)$$

But this is a separable equation. So:

$$\frac{vdv}{v+D}=\left(\frac{A}{y}-B \right)dy$$

$$v-D \ln (v+D)=A \ln y-B y+c_1$$

Getting back to the original function, we have:

$$\frac{\dot{y}}{y}-D \ln \left(\frac{\dot{y}}{y}+D \right)=A \ln y-B y+c_1$$

Or:

> $$\dot{y}-D y \ln (\dot{y}+D y)=(A-D) y \ln y-B y^2+c_1 y \tag{1}$$

This doesn't look like anything solvable, but it is indeed a 1st order ODE for $y$ only.

We also need to determine $c_1$ from the original system somehow, because the extra constant shouldn't be here.

---

We can actually resolve (1) for the derivative using Lambert W (product logarithm) function. Transforming the equation:

$$(\dot{y}+Dy)^{-Dy} e^{\dot{y}}=y^{(A-D)y}e^{-B y^2+c_1 y}$$

$$\frac{\dot{y}+Dy}{Dy} \exp \left(-\frac{\dot{y}+Dy}{Dy} \right)= \frac{e^{-1-c_1/D}}{ D} y^{-A/D} \exp \left(\frac{B}{D} y \right)$$

This has a solution:

$$\frac{\dot{y}+Dy}{Dy}=-W \left(-\frac{e^{-1-c_1/D}}{D} y^{-A/D} \exp \left(\frac{B}{D} y \right) \right)$$

> $$\dot{y}=- Dy \left(1+W \left(-\frac{e^{-1-c_1/D}}{D} y^{-A/D} \exp \left(\frac{B}{D} y \right) \right) \right) \tag{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Generally for this type of model one would start analysing what happens at equilibrium, i.e. whether there is a fixed point, if they are stable or not by looking at the Jacobian of the system.

First find the null-clines setting: $ 0= Ax - Bxy=f_1(x,y)$ and $Cxy - Dy=f_2(x,y)=0$ then you get $x=0,y=A/B$ for $f_1(x,y)$ and $y=0, x=D/C$ for $f_2(x,y)$. Finding the intersection of the null-clines you get two fixed points $(0,0)$ (both population are extinct) and $(D/C,A,B)$ (both populations are non-zero). Then if you look at the Jacobian (matrix of partial derivatives of $f_1(x,y), f_2(x,y)$) computed in the two fixed points you can understand which is the stable one and where the system ends up.

Alternatively you can solve this equation numerically. 
More info here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka–Volterra_equations  - this is a famous model you can find a lot of information around.

Comment: It would be nice to add that while closed form solution is likely to be non-existent, the predator-prey system admits non-trivial first integral and thus conservativ (and because of that we can have only saddles and centers).

Comment: @Evgeny True, one could look at the equation of the phase curves computing $dx/dy=(Ax-Bxy)/(Cxy-Dy)$ and integrate it to show this. In the question I just wanted point out an initial sketch of how to deal with such systems.