# How to find the extra constant after separating a system of ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

While trying to obtain an analytical solution for a system of 1st order ODEs from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1676569/269624), I have gained an extra constant (really, two of them), which I don't know how to find.

The original systems is:

$$\dot{x} = Ax - Bxy \\ \dot{y} = Cxy - Dy$$

To separate the functions, I differentiate the equation for $y$ and use several identities to obtain:

$$\ddot{y}=\frac{\dot{y}^2}{y}+(A-By)(\dot{y}+Dy)$$

Which I then integrate and get an implicit 1st order equation:

$$\frac{\dot{y}}{y}-D \ln \left(\frac{\dot{y}}{y}+D \right)=A \ln y-B y+c_1$$

Using Lambert function, I can solve for the derivative:

$$\dot{y}=- Dy \left(1+W \left(-\frac{e^{-1-c_1/D}}{D} y^{-A/D} \exp \left(\frac{B}{D} y \right) \right) \right)$$

Which formally offers a full analytical solution $t(y)$ as an indefinite integral (even though it's not likely to have an exact form in terms of known functions).

> How do I find the constant $c_1$? What 'initial conditions' should I use?

Because of the symmetry, we can repeat the same procedure for $x$ changing $C \leftrightarrow -B$ and $D \leftrightarrow -A$.

$$\frac{\dot{x}}{x}+A \ln \left(\frac{\dot{x}}{x}-A \right)=-D \ln x+C x+c_2$$

So, I suppose, there should be a way to find both $c_1$ and $c_2$ from the original system. But I wasn't able to do that yet.

I'm also aware that there are some problems with the results I obtained as the logarithms (and consequently Lambert function) will not always be defined in real numbers.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if this answers your question, but if you know $x$ and $y$ at (say) $t=0$, then from the ODEs you know $\dot y(0)$, so you can let $t=0$ in your implicit ODE and get $c_1$ from that.

Comment: @HansLundmark, thank you, I thought about this too, but shouldn't I be able to find $c_1,c_2$ without the initial conditions?

Comment: In more precise words, their values should not depend on the initial conditions at all

Comment: Yes, they should! Basically, you have rediscovered the constant of motion for the Lotka–Volterra equations, and a constant of motion is equal to its value at the initital time but that value depends on where you start.

Comment: @HansLundmark, thank you for the reference! I found some sources and will look them up. Still, I would really like to understand why these constants depend on the initial condtions, even though they appeared after integrating the new 2nd order equations once, and the initial conditions should determine the integrals for the original 1st order equations?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand the question...

Comment: @HansLundmark, sorry if I wasn't clear, essentially the last question is this: we have two initial conditions, $x(t_0), y(t_0)$. Say, we found a general solution $x(t,C_1), y(t,C_2)$, then we use the IC to find $C_1,C_2$. However, in this case I didn't find the general solutions yet, I only found explicit form $\dot{x}(x,t), \dot{y}(y,t)$, which means after integrating those, the aforementioned constants will appear. Which now makes it $4$ unknown constants to find $c_1,c_2,C_1,C_2$, but we only have $2$ initial conditions. How does that work?

Comment: I don't think the constants you find from the second-order $x$-equation are independent from the ones you find from the second-order $y$-equation. After all, each of these second-order equations on its own is equivalent to the whole first-order system that you started with.